# Make a stop button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pause

I thought this would be the easiest part but I guess I'm either having a brain fart or this is more difficult than I thought it'd be, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a stop button for this code. I've tried so many things that just don't seem to work. I want it so that when #stopbutton is pressed it stops audio. I've tried things like

```
function stopAudio() {
  audio.forEach(audio=>audio.pause());
}
$('#stopbutton').click(stopAudio);

function stopAudio() {
  audio.pause();
$('#stopbutton').click(stopAudio);
```

and someothers that didn't work

audio js

```
function playAudio(e) 
{
 let el = e.currentTarget;
 var audio = new Audio();
 var src = "mp3/" + el.id + ".mp3";
 audio.src = src;
 audio.play();
 return audio;
}
```

html

```
<a href="#/" id="stopbutton" class="stopbuttonf sound2button"></a>

<span><a href="#/" id="Sound1"  name="names2" class="buttonsf">Sound1</a><a href="#/" class="fav" title="Add To Favorites">X</a></span>
```

Between span is all in localStorage btw

This javascript might also be relevant

```
function createListeners() 
{
 let names = document.getElementsByName("names2");
 for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
 {
  let name = names[i];
  name.removeEventListener('click', playAudio);
  name.addEventListener('click', playAudio);
 }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() { createListeners(); });
$(document).on('click', '[name="names2"]', playAudio);
```

Comment: Where are you trying to add this *"stop button*" I don't see any attempt to create a function to do that? Please include the relevant `html` to go with your question. Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS oops, updated

Comment: Where are the other `html` elements? **names2** Also you are aware `$(document).on('` is `jQuery` right? Which means you will need to include/load the **jQuery Library** otherwise you will have syntax errors showing in the browser console.

Comment: @NewToJS yes, all the provided js (other than the stop button attemps) work

Comment: Why can't you just use the `<audio src="..." controls>` attribute to allow the audio to be paused?

Comment: Are you wanting to only allow one audio to play at a time or only one?? If you move `var audio = new Audio(); ` into the global scope so it can be accessed by other functions.

Comment: If you only want one to play at a time this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4a87zjdq/) might be of some use. I have cleaned it up a touch and replaced the `name` attributes with a `class`

Comment: @NewToJS that works great in the demo but it doesn't seem to work for when I apply it. I think it might be because "names2" comes from localStorage?

Comment: @JacobRidge Using the `name` attribute works just fine. [**JsFiddle Update**](https://jsfiddle.net/4a87zjdq/1/) Have you checked the browser console to check if you have any errors in here? If so then return and show them in your question.

Comment: @JacobRidge Also a example for dynamic elements. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4a87zjdq/2/)

Comment: @NewToJS I'd get a DOMException: The play() request was interrupted for audio.src = src; I wish the code you provided worked for me since it's much better than what I did, but I ended up making it work by putting name="names2" in the stop button element. I appreciate your help :)